# jruby rails4 eager_load doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have two models:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
  belongs_to :deposit_account    
  scope :not_test, -> { includes(:deposit_account).where("deposit_accounts.is_test_account is null or deposit_accounts.is_test_account != 1").references(:deposit_account) }
  ...
end

class DepositAccount < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :transactions, -> { order(:creation_date => :desc) }
  default_scope { where(:purpose => 'COUNTERFEIT') }
  scope :not_test, -> { where("is_test_account != 1") }
  ...
end
```

I tried to eager load the both tables with:

```
irb(main):008:0> request_transactions = Transaction.eager_load(:deposit_account)
**I polish the following output**
  SQL (6390.0ms)  SELECT "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."ID"                    AS t0_r0,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."DEPOSIT_ACCOUNT_ID"         AS t0_r1,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."TRANSACTION_TYPE"           AS t0_r2,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."TRACKING_ID"                AS t0_r3,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."AMOUNT"                     AS t0_r4,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."STATUS"                     AS t0_r5,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."TRANSACTION_COMMENT"        AS t0_r6,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."NOTIFICATION_EMAILS"        AS t0_r7,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."CREATED_BY"                 AS t0_r8,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."CREATION_DATE"              AS t0_r9,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."LAST_UPDATED_BY"            AS t0_r10,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."LAST_UPDATED_DATE"          AS t0_r11,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."FINISH_DATE"                AS t0_r12,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."PAYMENT_DATE"               AS t0_r13,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."MATCH_TYPE"                 AS t0_r14,
                    "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."ADDITIONAL_INFO"            AS t0_r15,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID"                             AS t1_r0,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."SELLER_ID"                      AS t1_r1,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."MARKETPLACE_ID"                 AS t1_r2,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE"                        AS t1_r3,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."TOTAL_DEPOSIT_BALANCE"          AS t1_r4,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."OUTSTANDING_DEPOSIT_REQUEST"    AS t1_r5,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."OUTSTANDING_REFUND_REQUEST"     AS t1_r6,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."CREATED_BY"                     AS t1_r7,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."CREATION_DATE"                  AS t1_r8,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."LAST_UPDATED_BY"                AS t1_r9,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."LAST_UPDATED_DATE"              AS t1_r10,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."IS_TEST_ACCOUNT"                AS t1_r11,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."RECORD_VERSION_NUMBER"          AS t1_r12,
                    "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."OUTSTANDING_CONFISCATE_REQUEST" AS t1_r13
                  FROM "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"
                  ON "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID"       = "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."DEPOSIT_ACCOUNT_ID"
                  AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT'

  DepositAccount Load (235.0ms)  SELECT "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS".* FROM "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS" WHERE "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID" = 143 AND ROWNUM <= 1
  DepositAccount Load (535.0ms)  SELECT "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS".* FROM "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS" WHERE "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID" = 143 AND ROWNUM <= 1
  DepositAccount Load (471.0ms)  SELECT "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS".* FROM "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS" WHERE "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID" = 147 AND ROWNUM <= 1
  DepositAccount Load (237.0ms)  SELECT "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS".* FROM "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS" WHERE "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID" = 138 AND ROWNUM <= 1
  ...
```

But it generates so many SQL, which means rails doesn't load eagerly I think. I expected the first clause is enough. Please help to eager load the tables. Thanks.

My environment:
jruby 1.7
rails 4.0

**EDIT1:**
I tried to run the same code on ruby 1.9 rails 4.0, the eager load works fine. So I guess this is caused by JRuby. Does anyone else have this problem?

Don't know if it matters, I use activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter in ruby 1.9 env, but JDBC driver in
JRuby. The database it oracle.

Comment: I suspect the generated SQL not being generated by Transaction.eager_load(:deposit_account) or your Transaction model is missing something. The reason why is the generated join condition. Where does this: AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' come from?

Comment: @tobago "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT' come from default_scope { where(:purpose => 'BOOK') }, which I made a mistake when post the question, it should be default_scope { where(:purpose => 'COUNTERFEIT') }.

Comment: I still suspect the generated SQL not being generated by Transaction.eager_load(:deposit_account) or your Transaction model is missing something. belongs_to: :deposit_account alone will never generate a combined join condition like: ON "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."ID" = "DEPOSIT_TRANSACTIONS"."DEPOSIT_ACCOUNT_ID" AND "DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTS"."PURPOSE" = 'COUNTERFEIT'

Comment: @tobago The SQL is exactly generated by the models and Transaction.eager_load(:deposit_account). The where clause is generated by the [default_scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by upgrading activerecord from activerecord-4.0.9 to activerecord-4.1.5. BTW, I use activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.7 as the adapter.